# Know any file compare utility for chunks of text?

Tags: search, comparison

Is there any file-compare utility-software that can help me compare chunks of text from two text files ?

As in, I want to know what chunks of text that are in one file can be found again in the second file. What I need to do is more like a 'compare and search' operation, not just a compare line by line.

I need this for finding common errors in application logs. Eg., I have a Java application and logs from two different days. I want to find out which stack-traces (that are actually chunks of text inside a text file) are common to both days.

Comment: What fileformat is the text you want to compare.

Comment: I think he/she said it quite a number of times already: text. I understand plain text files.

Comment: Have you tried any Difference/Comparing packages already?  There's many, some of which will (probably) do what you need.  See [What is a good text comparison tool for Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/56603/what-is-a-good-text-comparison-tool-for-windows) and perhaps [Best Diff Tool? (StackOverflow)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool)

Comment: @techie007 i have only tried Beyond Compare...

Answer (score 1):

You can try any number of free diff tools - I've used [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), which is a good open source tool that is available on a number of different platforms. I've been able to use it to compare several log files - there is a visual indication of which lines are different and common between these files (colors for differences, white/no color for common lines).

You may need to experiment a bit to tweak the app to do exactly what you're looking for, but it's a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Zero-times mentioned [CompareIT](http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp3.htm)

- It can *detect moved sections* and show these blocks
- It has support for RE, so you can *ignore some parts* of strings performing operations
- Automatch rules help on comparing structured sources